# TP4056 / DW01A / FS8205A

Tags: battery-charging, bms, tp4056

Does this circuit have to be implemented with a DW01A battery protection IC and a FS8205A dual MOSFET IC?

I want to make a simple circuit doing only the charging function of an 18650 battery.

The TP4056 has its own charging function, and it seems to be sufficient on its own.

I also read a [blog](https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056.html) saying that most commercial boards implementing these circuits are not well designed and do not use the DW01 circuit correctly.

I then asked myself the question of being satisfied with a TP4056 circuit alone in a context where I just want to make a simple load circuit.

The batteries will not be used at the same time. They will just be recharged and stored.

Answer (score 1):

The battery protection is for protection when the charger malfunctions.

Some batteries already have the protection built into the pack. These don't need separate protection.

Some batteries don't have built in protection. These batteries should be used with separate protection.

So it depends what kind of batteries you have and are they exchangeable.

And since you have user exchangeable 18650 batteries, some have internal protection, some don't.

It might be a good idea to add protection if unprotected batteries are used.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But what about the linked blob about a correct implementation and use of DW01?

Comment: What about it? What is the question about the blog then?

Comment: sorry. https://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/tp4056.html The blog seems to show that the use of the DW01A on commercial cards is not done correctly. So my question is related to this assumption and if I have to use it how do I do it correctly? Is the suggestion in the blog correct?

Comment: So in a nutshell, what does the blog suggest then? I can't access the content due to ads and other garbage popping up, it does not look like a link anyone should click.

Comment: With all the remarks received, I will implement with a DW01A. I also try to take into account the remarks of the blog. What do you think about this schematic ? [TP4056 - KICAD 6.0 - 2023.03.21](https://i.imgur.com/leXD8X3.jpg)

Comment: @hervema I'm following your schematic for TP4056 and DW01A. Did that schematic work out for you? Anything you'd change in hindsight?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly since months as is !